# SVG onClick with PHP

Tags: php, database, svg, onclick

Can I insert PHP database coding into the SVG onclick event?

I try to to use the onclick event to clear the database when being clicked on. I am new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

Make a php script that'll clear the database, then have javascript call the URL to the PHP script through AJAX once the SVG element has been clicked.

Comment: can show example i kind of don't understand what you mean. sorry bout this.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there are forms. You use these in order to send input data to for example a PHP file.

You can incorporate AJAX if what you want is a non-refreshed page request.